# What is the return value of spurious wake-ups?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, c11

In C11, the `cnd_timedwait` function is defined as followed:

> ```
> int cnd_timedwait( cnd_t* restrict cond, mtx_t* restrict mutex,
>                    const struct timespec* restrict time_point );
> ```
>
> Atomically unlocks the mutex pointed to by mutex and blocks on the condition variable pointed to by cond until the thread is signalled by `cnd_signal` or `cnd_broadcast`, or until the `TIME_UTC` based time point pointed to by time_point has been reached, or until a spurious wake-up occurs. The mutex is locked again before the function returns.
>
> **Return value**
>
> `thrd_success` if successful, `thrd_timedout` if the timeout time has been reached before the mutex is locked, or `thrd_error` if an error occurred.

When spurious wake-ups occur, would the function return `thrd_success` or `thrd_error`?

Although as far as I know, a spurious wake-up is not technically seen as an error.

Comment: The [reference for the equivalent C++ function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) documents the effect of spurious wake-ups with a bit more detail. It also has an overload to deal with them (with equivalent code that shows what you should do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `cnd_timedwait` could tell that the wake-up was spurious, it wouldn't do it. It doesn't do spurious wake-ups just to troll you. They happen because the value of the condition can change after the wake-up is scheduled but before the woken-up thread manages to do anything.

Since `cnd_timedwait` cannot tell whether a return is spurious or not, it's return value can't reflect that fact. It's a normal successful return. Your first task is to verify the condition.